# Does a JavaScript setTimeout function clear itself upon completion?

Tags: javascript

Does the `setTimeout` function clear/destroy itself when done, or do I need to manually call `clearTimeout` within the callback?

Answer (score 11):

It clears itself.

You only have to call clearTimeout if you want to cancel it before it fires.

Answer (score 8):

Yes it clears itself automatically when the timeout finishes and the function is fired.

The manual clearing is used to stop the countdown from finishing and the callback from firing. It has no function in the callback since the timeout is already cleared.

Comment: You dont have to do cleartimeout, It is used to stop timer