# Does setTimeout functions remove after it worked?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, settimeout

I want to add `data` on a div that comes from socket. And remove it after 5 seconds. (I am using socket.io client)

```
socket.on("data", (data) => {

    // add this data on div

    setTimeout(()=>{
      // remove data from div.
    }, 5000);

})
```

But a setTimeout function added each time a message arrives. May this a performance issue after some times? Should I remove it?

Comment: It's already [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31495690/does-a-javascript-settimeout-function-clear-itself-upon-completion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to worry about calling clearTimeout in your case. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391567/when-using-settimeout-do-you-have-to-cleartimeout#:~:text=You%20don't%20actually%20need,because%20setInterval%20usually%20runs%20indefinitely.&text=clearTimeout%20is%20only%20necessary%20for%20cancelling%20a%20timeout.).

If you are concerned about performance, here's a post about a promising [alternative](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/47889/alternative-to-setinterval-and-settimeout#:~:text=A%20new%20alternative%20is%20window,setTimeout()%20and%20setInterval()%20.) to setTimeout that could be helpful to you.